# Using edge loops for sharp edges without distorting the mesh?

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, edges, topology, distort

I've been trying to make a pirate ship a few days now, but when I was trying to sharpen out the edges of the ship's cabin, I ran into a problem. The edge loops I'm trying to sharpen out the cabin's edges with, are distorting the body of the ship that should not have any creases. The body and the cabin should be in one piece and the transition from the blocky cabin to the round surface of the ship should be smooth. On the picture the problems are circled.
[image]
I have watched CGmasters viedo,  where he explaines how to avoid pinching from additional detailes by shrinkwrapping detailed mesh (with pinching) to the same object that is not detailed (base mesh).

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3rlMzsBWtPY

I'm trying to create the base mesh that I later shrinkwrap an even more detailed one onto. The problem is that I may or may not be so noob, that I don't even know how to create the base mesh without pinching. I HAVE tried controlling the shrinkwrap modifier using vertex groups to only transform the part of the model that doesn't need to stay sharp and edgy, but that didn't work well because of a seam that appeared.

I hope everyone gets my point :)

I'll also try to upload the blender file for everyone to play around.
[image]

Additional picture showing my topology
[image: additional picture showing my topology]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to move some vertices to make it smoother:

[image]

Comment: That's a lot better... I don't know why I didn't come up with this myself

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly what you want its the body of the ship without those 2 distorted edges loops. You can dissolve them as they are not really needed for support.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I have tried this... I mean, this is OK, but I'm still left with pinch in the transition from Ships body to cabin. As I mentioned the transition should be smooth.